# What is the problem if we use air as clad in fiber communication?

Tags: fiber-optics

The refractive index of air is approximately 1 and that of core possibly be 1.5.

The refractive index of clad could be 1.48 or 1.45.

The refractive index of clad and refractive index of air both are less than the refractive index of core.

So, what is the problem if we use air as clad?

As far I study that any lower refractive index than that of core could come in touch of fiber removing the total internal reflection property of fiber. But this could be ensured by giving only the coating over it. Of course I would take the refractive index of coating material less than that of core.

So, what are the other possible problems?

Note: This question could be among basics of fiber optics. As a beginner in this field, I could not gather the information from googling and studying some articles.

Comment: what does "clad" mean in this context ?

Comment: @JoeBlow the part of fiber having different refractive index than core, more specifically less than the refractive index of core. This also popular as cladding also. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, is it "wrapped around" the core, or ?

Comment: @JoeBlow Absolutely right you are. But clad also made of glass most of the time or in practical but having different refractive index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Floris mentions, an air cladding means that anything touching the outside of the fiber disturbs the waveguide properties.

Two other practical issues:

- The surface roughness becomes critical to the fiber loss (and difficult to maintain). I believe that this was actually tried in the early days, and it's covered in Jeff Hecht's history of fiber optics book, *City of Light: The Story of Fiber Optics*.
- Single mode fiber would be less robust, due to its very small diameter. In conventional fiber, the cladding and jacket give the physical support of a 250 um (typically) diameter glass fiber, while the light is restricted to the ~9 um core.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that if you have air as clad, then nothing may touch your fiber. This means that you have to suspend the fiber in air - at any point where you touch it, you would change the reflective properties. This would result to dispersion and losses in the signal.

By ensuring that the reflection takes place on an inner boundary, you make the fiber robust to whatever environment you place it in. That's a very important practical consideration.

You wrote

> But this could be ensured by giving only the coating over it. Of course I would take the refractive index of coating material less than that of core.

The moment you have a coating, you have changed the definition of what the cladding is. The coating you propose is the cladding... so it's no longer air.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it was a typo. I actually wanted to write 'less'. Updated the question. Sorry again and Thanks.

Comment: No problem - changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Does not dispersion occur after cladding? As far I know, it exists though.